# Trying to build a Ext.data.Store with proxy, the request is fired but no data is pushed

Tags: extjs, proxy, store

I'm having the problem of my life.

Everytime I want to build a simple `Ext.data.Store` with a proxy (ajax), the request is fired I can see in my server the request at same time I put store.load(), but when I put some callback/check to my store like `store.data.items` or `store.getProxy().reader.rawData`, I got nothing.

Here is the code. It's simple, like the ExtJs doc's example:

```
Ext.define('User', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {
             name: 'id',
             type: 'int'
         },
         {
             name: 'Rule',
             type: 'string'
         },
     ]
 });

var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     model: 'User',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '/product/getrule/'+product_id,
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'result["rules"]'
         }
     },
     autoLoad: true
 });
```

The json is like this:

```
"result":{
    "name": "producttemplatte1",
    "rules":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "rule":"rule1"
        }
     ],
    "active": true 
}
```

I've tried everything. `Ext.Ajax.request`s too. I add the data from Ajax responses to the store and all, but the combobox store won't load (I guess it is because the asynchronous "A" from Ajax doesn't want to :/)

Comment: Just asking, is the "json" you've provided, that is returned from the server, enclosed between curly brackets?

Comment: Which version of Ext is this? Recent versions have "rootProperty" instead of "root" on the reader. Have you tried root: 'result.rules' instead of root: 'result["rules"]'

Comment: @KevinCollins ExtJS v. 4.1.3. Unfortunately, this version don't have this `rootProperty`  :/ I tried `result.rules`, but i have no success. Life ... :/

Comment: @scebotari yes! Enclosed between brackets.

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) that showcases your issue. Here is one that I've created: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qfd, and it works as expected.

Comment: Do the field names in your model match the json string exactly?  In your example you have `Rule` in the model, but `rule` in the json.